# Can you edit a job in SQL Agent if you arent the owner or sysadmin?

Tags: sql, sql-agent-job

In a previous job I had as a Database Administrator III, our team was responsible for creating and maintaining SQL agent jobs that ran various database maintenance tasks and we would often use the standard maintenance plan wizard that comes with SSMS.
A common issue we would come across while maintaining these jobs had to do with the ability to edit the job if you weren’t the owner.  It was standard for us to create the job and use a common dba account so that all the dbas could edit the job but from time to time a dba would create the job using their own personal AD account and not the standard dba.  This didn’t cause too much inconvenience for us because we, as DBAs, also had the sysadmin privs so we could edit the job anyway.  But this got me thinking.  Was there a way to allow someone who wasn’t an owner of a job the ability to modify the job without granting them too much privilege like giving them sysadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Any OOP programmer is familiar with the concept of overriding a method.  This is basically the same idea but overriding a system stored proc with a custom stored proc with one line of code that allows to achieve our goal.

Only members of sysadmin are able to edit jobs that they do not own.
If you create a copy of the dbo.sp_update_job as dbo.sp_update_job_override but add an ‘Grant Execute On’ at the end you can override it.

Put this line of code on the end of your copy of dbo.sp_update_job.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[sp_update_job_override] TO [SQLAgentOperatorRole]
```

So if you grant the user the SQLAGENTOPERATORROLE they will be able to make this call and it will complete successfully.

```
USE msdb ;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_update_job_override
    @job_name = N'SampleJob',
    @new_name = N'Sample Job New',
    @description = N'Sample job for demonstration purposes.',
    @enabled = 0 ;
GO
```

Edit...I found an article from Boris Hristov on this topic..thanks Boris.